# Format SD card to be internal storage, restart phone, missing SD card?

Tags: reboot, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, motorola, formatting

I am running on Android 8.0.0 on a Motorola E5 Cruise, I tried to use my Motorola to format my SD card as internal storage, then I restart my phone and it says the SD card is missing when I have not removed it, and if I try to do any in phone troubleshooting that I know how to do the only option is to reformat the device again which then would defeat the purpose of why I'm trying to format it as internal storage, is there anything I can do?

I have access to a Linux PC to use for the purposes of reformatting should that be beneficial for this, but I would like to know a step-by-step, please.

I have no need to recover the data. I just want to use it as an internal SD, or if I need to get another SD to replace it but would want to know the exact parameters of any SD I would need to get so I don't waste my money.

The first image I expected before the restart, but the rest of the images are what happened afterwards.
[image: Pre Restart]
[image: Post Restart A]
[image: Post Restart B]
[image: Post Restart C]

Comment: what dialog says that? it's intended SD Card disappeared for the sake of becoming adoptable-storage (unsupported on Oreo FBE)

Comment: I will add attachments of images clarifying if I can figure out how

Comment: @alecxs I added images clarifying what I meant, clearly not what's supposed to happen 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue ended up being the fact that the SD card had previously been used on a different device? When I bought a brand new SD card, same specs but different brand, I had absolutely no issue.

Must be UHS-1.